# Reading File - fgets reading \n where is not

Tags: c

I'm making this code to read files that contain a matrix or multiple ones.
There is also a first line which contains some info about the matrix above each one.

This is the code:

```
void loadfile(char *filename, maps **head, maps **tail){

    FILE *file;
    maps *aux;
    char buffer[MAX_CHAR];
    bool flag = true;
    int current_line = 1;

    /* open file */
    file = openfile(filename, "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_CHAR, file) != NULL){

        while(strcmp(buffer, "\n") == 0){
            fgets(buffer, MAX_CHAR, file);
            flag = true;
            printf("HERE\n");   
        }

        if(flag == true){
            printf("Dayum\n");
            aux = emptymap();
            settings(buffer, aux);
            managelist(head, tail, aux);
            flag = false;
            current_line = 1;
        }else{
            fillboard(buffer, aux, current_line);
            current_line++;
        }
    }

    /* close file */
    fclose(file);
}
```

[For some files it works okay, like this one:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3w5.png)

[But for others like this, it doesn't:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnG7D.png)

It gets stuck in this while loop without any reason:

```
 while(strcmp(buffer, "\n") == 0){
        fgets(buffer, MAX_CHAR, file);
        flag = true;
        printf("HERE\n");   
    }
```

I need help, because I really don't understand why is this happening!

Comment: Check the return value of `fgets()`.

Comment: Don't post images of data. Instead, edit your question using the  `edit` button just below the tags and paste the data directly into the question. Thanks.

Comment: Bob Jarvis i'm new on this so i'm still getting used to! Thanks for the tip! :)

Mopp that's what i did now, and IT WORKS! Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, you might want to take the [tour] of the site to learn a bit about how it works (*and* you'll get a badge for it). There's more info in the [help], too.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner call to `fgets` (inside the `while(strcmp)` loop) is not checked. And, quoting C11 (N1570) 7.21.7.2/3:

> If end-of-file is encountered and no
>   characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a
>   null pointer is returned.

So if the buffer contains just `'\n'` and that was the last character in the file, you'll be stuck in the loop forever because the buffer will not be overwritten.

Comment: Wow! You are amazing! I edited my code, adding: 

    if(fgets(buffer, MAX_CHAR, file) == NULL){
        return;
    }

And it's working apparently now! Much appreciated the help!